# Solutions to Hill equation with two coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, periodic-functions

I'm searching for quasiperiodic solutions of the Hill equation

$$
H \psi := \frac{d^2 \psi}{d z^2} + V(z) \psi (z) = 0
$$

where

$$
V(z) := \theta_0 + 2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \theta_n \cos{(2 n z)}
$$

in the special case of $\theta_1 \neq 0$, some $\theta_n = \theta_1 / n$ and all other $\theta_j = 0$ for $j>1 , j \neq n$. The coefficients $\theta_1$ and thus $\theta_n$ are fixed. I'm trying to find $\theta_0$ for that such quasiperiodic solutions with $\psi(z+\pi) = e^{i\mu z}\psi(z)$ with $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$ exist.

This equation is the time-independent Schrödinger equation for a superconducting qubit called the fluxonium qubit (after some simplifications).

Comment: What precisely do you mean by quasiperiodic solutions? Even in the case of one nonzero $\theta$ you have the Mathieu equation. In any case, the book *Hill's equation* by Magnus and Winkler contains many relevant theorems. In particular see chapter 4

Comment: @Sal With quasiperiodic solutions I mean solutions that satisfy $\psi(z+\pi) = e^{i\mu z}\psi(z)$ with $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$. So that a solution only "acquires" a phase factor when translating it by the period $\pi$ of the "potential" $V(z)$.

I am aware that for $\theta_0 \neq 0$ and some $\theta_j \neq 0$ for $j\neq 0$ the problem is just the mathieu equation. However I am particularly interested in the case where  $\theta_1 \neq 0$ and an **additional** $\theta_n \neq 0$ with $n\neq 0, 1$.

Thank you for the book suggestion!

Comment: I was unclear- I meant: even when just one $\theta$ is nonzero, we have the Mathieu equation, whose solutions are non-elementary, so your quest to *find* solutions may be difficult